# Using PHP Function parse_ini_file() on an invalid ini file

Tags: php, parsing, ini

I have a ini file comming from an external program, that I have no control over. The ini file does not have double quotes around the values Example:

```
[Setup]
C SetupCode=Code of the currently installed setup (JOW
C machine configuration). Use a maximum of 8 characters.
```

using parse_ini_file() gives me:  `syntax error, unexpected ')'`
I guess i should read the file raw in php and add double quotes around the values like this:

```
[Setup]
C SetupCode="Code of the currently installed setup (JOW
C machine configuration). Use a maximum of 8 characters."
```

Is this the best practice, and if so how would I do it?

Comment: ini files normally do not require double quotes around the values. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

Comment: @PaulH There is no formal standard format for INI files. It's an *informal* standard. Some dialects support quoting (in particular, Windows' INF files, which use an INI format for a very particular purpose), some don't, and others may require it.

Comment: @Rhymoid yes, but Mini seems to think quotes are necessary for `parse_ini_file()`

Comment: @PaulH I thought Mini thought that quoting allows for line breaks in values, which normally ends a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The INI file format is an **informal** standard. Variations exist, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file.
`C` seems to stand for Comment, but `parse_ini_file()` does not understand that. So read the ini file in a string, replace the `C` with `;`, then use `parse_ini_string()`

```
<?php
// $ini_string = file_get_contents(...);

// test data
$ini_string = "
[Setup]
C SetupCode=Code of the currently installed setup (JOW
C machine configuration). Use a maximum of 8 characters.
SetupCode=my C ode
";

// replace 'C ' at start of line with '; ' multiline
$ini_string = preg_replace('/^C /m', '; ', $ini_string);

$ini_array = parse_ini_string($ini_string);


print_r($ini_array); // outputs Array ( [SetupCode] => my C ode )
```

Comment: I'm delete my answer, but you can use `str_replace` this is optimal for replace text, `str_replace('C ','; ',$ini_string)`

Comment: @Naumov str_replace will do the trick in this case, but not in all cases. C shall only be replaced if first character of a line followed by space.

Comment: Ty, This worked for me, I thought it was because it was missing the double quotes around the value, but as you said it's the "C" that probbaly stands "Comment" infront of the line that messed with parse_ini